# Binning which variables?

Tags: predictive-modeling, preprocessing, binary

I will try to implement a k-means algorithm over this dataset:

```
Team_Categorical  CreditAmount_Numeric   Retired?_Binary
       A                 15.3                   1
       B                 12                     0
       C                 6.2                    1
```

In order to apply k-means algorithm I need to transform the categorical variables into numeric. So I will apply binning transformaton over the Team_Categorical field. So I will have this dataset:

```
A    B   C  CreditAmount_Numeric   Retired?_Binary
1    0   0          15.3                 1
0    1   0          12                   0
0    0   1          6.2                  1
```

My question is: Should I transform CreditAmount_Numeric to binary too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you need not transform the numeric to binary variable(you meant binning right?).

I will try to explain it with the above example:

[image: snapshot]
Let's start with row-1 where A = 1 , B =0 , C=0 so it means that you are talking about A. So the value of CreditAmount_Numeric belongs to A and the retired binary value also belongs to A. Similarly, you can deduce for the rest records.

Conclusion is that you need not do any transformation on your numeric variable.

Comment: But for example, in K-Means it will be calculating centroides with binaries and numerics? Like making the average with all the numerics?

Comment: yes it takes centroides of the numeric variables and perform the clustering